# A question about inverse modulo a number.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, solution-verification, diophantine-equations

If $xy \equiv 1 \pmod a$, can I write $x \equiv \frac{1}{y} \pmod a$.

I was thinking about this while solving [IMO 2005 P4,](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2803320/242) so in particular can I write $$2^{p-2} + 3^{p-2} + 6^{p-2}\equiv\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{6} \pmod p?$$

Comment: Normally not... it's more common to write $y^{-1}$. Also, if $a$ is not prime, then there are element that are not invertible.

Comment: What Surb commented.  Typically, you have to **first** demonstrate that there exists a unique integer $k \in \{0,1,2,\cdots, (a-1)\}$ such that $ky \equiv 1\pmod{a}.$  Usually, this demonstration is not that hard; in fact it is often immediate.  However, the issue should be considered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as $\gcd(a,y)=1$, yes, you could. If not, then you can't.

Find some integer solution to $my+na=1$, say by the extended Euclidean algorithm. Modulo $a$ this yields $my\equiv 1$, which means that $m$ corresponds to $\frac 1y$.

As noted in the comments above, though, it is more common in modular arithmetic to write $y^{-1}$.

Comment: so if i was writing the solution i have mentioned in the second para of my question, would it be allowed?

Comment: @Aditya_math As long as $p$ is a prime greater than $3$ (or any other number divisible by neither $2$ nor $3$, such as $35$), then yes, that would make sense.